# SoapUI - Assert if property transfer value is in returned list

Tags: soapui, assertion

This is my first post, so please, be gentle :)

In the free SoapUI version, I would like to test some REST APIs with the following simple scenario:
POST, than a GET to check post.
In my test suite, I have a test case that has the following steps:
1. post;
2. property transfer;
3. get.

The thing that makes it complicated is that the POST response does not contain any parameter-value pairs. It returns a json with only a value which is actually an id (it corresponds to `taskId` parameter).

In the property transfer step, I have selected the POST as Source, Response as Property and XPath as Path language (using jsonPath returns null).
In the Target, I've selected the Test Suite, with propertyTest as Property and XPath as Path language (here I receive the value if I'm using JSONPath).
When I run the property transfer, it returns correctly the transferred value.

Finally, at my last step - GET:
The GET only returns a list if a filter is in place, so I have given the corresponding parameter and value in the GET Method, when creating it (the filter is by `organizationId`). This method returns a json which has all the `taskId`s (named 'id' in this list) for that corresponding `organizationId` (named `ownerOrganizatioId` in this list).
In the test step, I want to make an assertion that the new value response from the POST is actually in the retrieved list. I am trying to do this using a JsonPath Match assertion.

If I use this expression: `$.[?(@.ownerOrganizationId==2)].id` it will actually return all the ids (`taskId`s) from the database.
So far so good. But now, I would like to assert that the new id value is actually in this list.
I know that I can use this expression `{#TestSuite1#TaskTypeIdPropertyTransfer}` to use the posted value, but what I don't know is: what is the assert expression to check if it is in the list?

Thank you for taking the time to read and investigate this and please let me know if more details are needed.

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

If I understood i correctly, you may need to do some Groovy script something like this:

```
def id = {insert something to assign the id you need to find in the list}
def idList = {insert something to fetch the list}
def idFound = false
for (def currentId : idList) {
    if (id.equals(currentId)) {
        idFound = true
        break
    }
}
assert(idFound==true)
```